# How to create p12 file from Private key file?

Tags: openssl

I have a Private key with a secure passphrase. How to create .p12 file from it?
I have tried the command
`>openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey myprivatekey -out test.p12`

But nothing is happening. How to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of pkcs12 [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html). I think you also need to mention certfile. In PKCS #12, a certificate and a private needed. Optionally you can include certificate chain by giving CAfile and CApath.